# my angular - app not working using `gulp`. any one help me?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

i am building a `angular` application using `gulp`. my static `index.html` is working fine.

But the `angular` app not responding at all. as well i am not getting any error too. I guess that, the module itself not loaded here.

I don't know what is wrong i made here. any one figure out it please?

my `gulpfile.js` :

```
var paths   = require('./gulp/paths'),
gulp            = require('gulp'),
args            = require('yargs').argv,
fileSytems  = require('file-system'),
ngConstant  = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
rename      = require('gulp-rename')
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

var ENV = args.env || "mock";

gulp.task('constants', function () {
  var myConfig = require('./envs.json');
  var envConfig = myConfig[ENV];
  return ngConstant({
    name: "app.constants",
    constants: envConfig,
    stream: true
  })
  .pipe(rename('constants.config.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('source/app'));
});


gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
  browserSync.init({
    server:{
      baseDir : './source'
    },

    port : 9999

  })
})


gulp.task('default', ['constants', 'browser-sync'], function(){

  gulp.watch( ['source/app/components/*.js']);
  gulp.watch( ['source/**/*.html'], browserSync.reload);

});
```

my angular file `index.module.js` : ( As a test )

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
    angular.module('myApp.directives', []);

    var modules = [ 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.directives' ];

    angular.module('myApp', modules);

    angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.name = "World";

    }]);


})();
```

my `index.html` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app="myApp">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- libraries -->
    <script src="./lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <title>My App Proto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <h2>My Application goes here!</h2>
    <h2>{{ 2 + 2 }}</h2> //i am not getting any result! error too
    <img src="" alt="">

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="./app/index.module.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="./app/components/mainController.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

the command i am running for gulp to start my app is : 'gulp' ( default )

Any one help me please?

Comment: Please don't just `down-vote` and `close`, I need the wrong what i do here

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, this is what I am not able to understand

Comment: @gaurav5430 - do you want to have a look my app?